# Body deformed when changing name of vertex groups

Tags: modeling, vertices

I’m having this weird moment when renaming the vertex groups, the body starts getting deformed. What do I do?

Comment: maybe your mesh is rigged and renaming the vertex groups changes the relation between vertex group names and bone names.

Comment: As lemon says you need to keep the same name as the bones, otherwise the bones can't control the vertex group anymore, if you really need to rename the vertex groups what you could do is rename the bones as well

Answer (score 1):

To figure out what is happening with your mesh, first ask yourself a few questions:

1. Am I using an armature modifier?
   Armature modifiers utilize vertex groups with specific names to deform your mesh. They reference them through the names, so editing them results in "vertex group not found" issues.
2. What exactly am I trying to achieve by renaming the vertex groups? This is an open question, can you clarify further? What's the purpose of renaming them?
3. Are there any other modifiers I am using on my mesh? Do they use these vertex groups? Try to enable/disable each modifier one by one to check which one might have an effect on your mesh.
4. If all of those don't help, we might need more information from you. A few screenshots of your deformed mesh and the vertex groups prior and after renaming. Modifiers, and just anything related to the issue.